# Airconsole Ratelimiter and Unity

Tags: airconsole

I was trying to use the ratelimiter in my project in Unity, but couldn't get it working.

When I add the rate-limiter.js script, from the airconsole-controls github to my Unity project. I get errors concerning missing semicolons, which can be seen in this picture:

[Semicolon errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HwyVr.png)

When I add these semicolons, I get a lot of new errors, seen in this picture:

[New errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MpAQA.png)

I don't really know what the problem is. Am I required to import the rate-limiter.js script? Nothing happens when I try to use the ratelimiter without it. It doesn't send the data to my OnMessage, in my other script, where I print out all data, which works fine without ratelimiter.

My instantiation of airconsole in controller.html looks like this:

```
var airconsole;
var rateLimiter = new RateLimiter(airconsole);

function init() {
        airconsole = new AirConsole({ "orientation": "portrait", "device_motion": 100});
}

function move(amount) {
        rateLimiter.message(AirConsole.SCREEN, {move: amount})
    }
```

The part of the other script where I print out the data looks like this:

```
void OnMessage(int device_id, JToken data)
{
print(data);
}
```

I have also tried instantiating ratelimiter in function init and I also tried it without the function init like this.

```
var airconsole = new AirConsole({ "orientation": "portrait", "device_motion": 100});
var rateLimiter = new RateLimiter(airconsole);
```

Do anyone know what I am doing wrong or how to correctly use ratelimiter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The AirConsole RateLimiter does not work on the screen inside the AirConsole Unity Plugin. It is intended for HTML5 controllers & HTML5 Screens.

Just to be clear: The RateLimiter works fine in html5 controllers that talk to unity games, but not inside unity games.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. 

I should be able to send data from my html controller, using RateLimiter, to a script in Unity, right? And without importing the rate-limiter.js?

The only place I use RateLimiter at the moment, is in my html controller. But I can't acess the data in Unity.

Comment: Yes, using the RateLimiter to send data from an HTML controller to a unity project works fine. Rate-limiter.js only needs to be included in the controller. To debug you can temporarily remove the rate limiter from the controller, if that works,it should also work when including it correctly.